# Karma testing using selenium docker containers

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I've been tasked with fixing a CI pipeline at work. Additionally, the pipeline should be switched to docker and use selenium browser containers (for example selenium/standalone-edge). I hit a roadblock, though, as I couldn't properly connect the node container and the selenium container.

If it's relevant, we're using gitlab-ci and start the browser container using services.

```yaml
js-tests:
  image: "node:$version"
  services:
  - name: "selenium/standalone-$BROWSER:$BROWSER_VERSION"
    alias: "selenium_standalone"
...
```

Related dependencies:

```
karma-webdriver-launcher 1.0.8
@chiragrupani/karma-chromium-edge-launcher 2.3.1
karma 4.4.1
karma-chrome-launcher 3.1.0
karma-coverage 2.0.1
karma-firefox-launcher 1.3.0
karma-jasmine 3.1.0
karma-mocha-reporter 2.2.5
karma-sourcemap-loader 0.3.7
karma-webpack 4.0.2
```

I'm configuring a customLauncher with following settings:

```js
browserName + '-Webdriver' = {
    base: "WebDriver",
    heartbeatInterval: 10000,
    captureTimeout: 300000,
    config: {
       port: seleniumPort,
       hostname: seleniumHostname
    },
    browserName: browserName + "-Webdriver",
    name: 'Karma'
}
```

`seleniumPort` and `seleniumHostname` are derived from the environment variable `SELENIUM__STANDALONE_{browserName}_PORT`, generated based on the selenium container in use. `browserName` is from the same environment variable used to start the browser container.

We later set browsers to `[Edge-Webdriver]` and push the plugin `'@chiragrupani/karma-chromium-edge-launcher'` into the plugins list (which was before set to `['karma-jasmine', 'karma-mocha-reporter', 'karma-sourcemap-loader', 'karma-webdriver-launcher', 'karma-webpack', 'karma-coverage']`).

That seems to be correct, but when running, I receive the following output:

```
26 09 2023 10:19:56.658:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 09 2023 10:19:56.661:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Edge-Webdriver with concurrency unlimited
26 09 2023 10:19:56.787:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver
26 09 2023 10:20:56.792:WARN [launcher]: Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
26 09 2023 10:20:56.863:INFO [WebDriver]: Killed Karma test.
26 09 2023 10:20:56.871:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver again (1/2).
26 09 2023 10:21:56.914:WARN [launcher]: Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
26 09 2023 10:21:56.947:INFO [WebDriver]: Killed Karma test.
26 09 2023 10:21:56.949:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver again (2/2).
26 09 2023 10:22:57.004:WARN [launcher]: Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
26 09 2023 10:22:57.031:INFO [WebDriver]: Killed Karma test.
26 09 2023 10:22:57.033:ERROR [launcher]: Edge-Webdriver via Remote WebDriver failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

I tried switching out the base, with mostly little success.
Is there anything wrong with my setup? Or are there any example projects that implement karma tests using selenium-standalone containers?

Edit:
I added a bit more logging to my code. The `hostname` in the general karma configuration is set to the IP of the docker container hosting the tests. Therefore, I assume the browser container should be able to reach the karma server hosting the tests.